# How to show empty rows in a listview using cursoradapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

i have a Sqlite database table which has the following columns: _id, key (int), name (text). here key is a unique key. Suppose i have the following rows in the table:

### _id | key | name

### 1   | 2   | n2

### 2   |  3  |  n3

### 3   |  5  |  n5

### 4   |  6  |  n6

Now, i have to show a listview of this table where starting from key=1, i will show the key followed by name if key is present but i'll show key followed by 'not assigned' if key is not present in the table. How can I do this using a CursorAdapter?
e.g. for the table above I will show the list view like this:

1. not assigned
2. n2
3. n3
4. not assigned
5. n5
6. n6

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the two easiest ways :

- Create empty rows for all possible keys

  When you insert a new row in your database, let's say with key = 9, check what is the current highest key in your database (here, 6) and create empty rows (with name set to `NULL` or an empty string) between this and your new row.
  Then in your `CursorAdapter` you can easily display "not assigned" if the name is empty.
- Subclass `CursorWrapper`

  Another way is to subclass [`CursorWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) and override `move()`, `moveToNext()`, `getCount()`, ... to simulate empty rows. This is more flexible and requires less space and database operations, but some methods may be tricky to implement (how will you write `getCount()`? it should return the highest key, but how to find it efficiently ?).

Answer (score 0):

With a CursorAdapter I don't think you easily can. The dataset for such an adapter is a cursor over a results set from your database. You don't have those 'not assigned' rows in your results set and changing your SQL to get them will be awkward to do. If you really want to do that, you would need to RIGHT JOIN to another table of sequential numbers (on your_table.key = number_table.number) using IFNULL(name, 'Not assigned') in the SELECT list. You'd also need to use a raw query for that.

I suggest an ArrayAdapter instead, built by iterating over your results cursor and identifying the gaps as you go. Example pseudo code:

```
listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
int count = 1;
while (cursor.moveToNext())
{
    get key and name from cursor row
    while (count < key)  //Add 'not assigned' for any gaps
    {
        listArray.add(String.valueOf(count) + ":" + "not assigned");
        count++;
    }
    listArray.add(String.valueOf(count) + ":" + name);
    count++;
}
cursor.close();
```

Then use listArray as the dataset for the ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your database say which elements should be displayed in your list and you want to show list items which are not in your database. I would say you need something like a helper in the middle between database and view component to load your database stuff, add the missing rows to a complete set of data and give this set of data (sqlite data + missing rows) to a adapter class. Then knows your adapter the number of rows in your list and can create this number of views. Now you have the same number of data objects and views.

Maybe this can help you. Its a example from google to convert your Cursor to Objects. Then you can use a ArrayAdapter.

- [ObjectCursorDemo](http://code.google.com/p/platform-features-talk-io-2013/source/browse/src/com/example/iotalk/ObjectCursorDemo.java?r=5f15f85f9fb0e18f2d35a341e6723955b934d113)
- [ObjectCusorLoader](http://code.google.com/p/platform-features-talk-io-2013/source/browse/src/com/example/iotalk/ObjectCursorLoader.java?spec=svn5f15f85f9fb0e18f2d35a341e6723955b934d113&r=5f15f85f9fb0e18f2d35a341e6723955b934d113)
- [ObjectCursor](http://code.google.com/p/platform-features-talk-io-2013/source/browse/src/com/example/iotalk/ObjectCursor.java?r=5f15f85f9fb0e18f2d35a341e6723955b934d113)